# removeEventListener and passing attributes

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to remove the addEventListener and I get why it's not working. You can't remove it from a anonymous function like that. But I have no idea how I combine this issue with passing attributes.

```
function addClick() {
    if ( allPlaced ) {
        alert("works");
        for (let i = 0; i < 24; i++ ) {
            document.getElementById("position" + i 
            ).removeEventListener("click", function () { 
                placeFunc(i); 
            });
            document.getElementById("position" + i 
            ).addEventListener("click", function () { 
                moveFunc(i); 
            });
        } 
    } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < 24; i++ ) {
            document.getElementById("position" + i 
            ).addEventListener("click", function () { 
                placeFunc(i); 
            });
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use one listener and check `allPlaced ` in callback?

Comment: you could tack each handler function onto the element to keep a ref around to feed removeEventListener. you could push `i` to an attrib/prop so that you can delegate the whole thing and not fuss with removal

Comment: Why not set a HTML5 data attribute on each element `data-index="1"` and read it off within your event handler using `element.getAttribute('data-index')`?